# libGDX Classes relationship

Tags: class, libgdx

I am trying Libgdx Game Class to make a game.And I am following a book.There is an example. Example has 4 classes and 1 DesktopLauncher. DesktopLauncher use StarfishCollector3() class to main function.  Despite I dont call create method and render method which are in GameBeta abstract class to StarfishCollector3, the project is working.Can you explain what I dont know.

```
    class StarfishCollector3 : GameBeta() {
    var turtle:Turtle=null
    var starfish:ActorBeta=null
    var ocean:ActorBeta=null
    var winMessage:ActorBeta=null
    var win:Boolean = true

    override fun initialize() {
        ocean= ActorBeta()
        ocean.setTexture(Texture( Gdx.files.internal("water.jpg")  ))
        mainStage.addActor(ocean)

        starfish = ActorBeta();
        starfish.setTexture(Texture(Gdx.files.internal("starfish.png")) );
        starfish.setPosition( 380F,380F );
        mainStage.addActor( starfish );

        turtle = Turtle()
        turtle.setTexture( Texture(Gdx.files.internal("turtle-1.png")) )
        turtle.setPosition( 20F,20F )
        mainStage.addActor( turtle )

        winMessage = ActorBeta();
        winMessage.setTexture( Texture(Gdx.files.internal("you-win.png")) );
        winMessage.setPosition( 180F,180F );
        winMessage.setVisible( false );
        mainStage.addActor( winMessage );
        win = false }

    override fun update(dt: Float) {
        if (turtle.overlaps(starfish as ActorBeta)){
            starfish.remove()
            winMessage.setVisible(true)} }
}
abstract class GameBeta: Game() {
    protected var mainStage: Stage=null
   
 abstract  fun initialize()
    
override fun create() {`
        mainStage = Stage()
        initialize() }

    abstract  fun update(dt:Float)
    .
    override fun render() {
        var dt= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()
        mainStage.act()
        update(dt)  
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F,0F,0F,1F)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        mainStage.draw()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be better if you were to include the code from your picture as well.

Answer (score 0):

The heirarchy of StarfishCollector3 is that it extends GameBeta, which extends Game, which implements ApplicationListener.

In DesktopLauncher you instantiate a StarfishCollector3 and pass it as an implicit ApplicationListener to an Application constructor by calling something like `new LwjglApplication(starfishCollectior, config);`. When you instantiate that LwjglApplication (or Lwjgl3Application or AndroidApplication, etc. depending on backend), the constructor of that Application class sets up the game engine. It creates all the classes for managing OpenGL and drawing the game in a repeating loop, pausing and resuming, etc.

So the Application class is using your StarfishCollector3 as an ApplicationListener and calling its relevant lifecycle methods at the appropriate times.